# How to fetch and parse all existing pages based on site pager?

Tags: python, parsing, web-crawler, scrapy, html-parser

Could somebody provide code or examples regarding the subject?

Example HTML:

```
...
<dd><span class="active">1</span></dd>
<dd><a href="http://rabota.ua/jobsearch/vacancy_list?regionId=1&amp;pg=2">2</a></dd>
<dd><a href="http://rabota.ua/jobsearch/vacancy_list?regionId=1&amp;pg=3">3</a></dd>
<dd><a href="http://rabota.ua/jobsearch/vacancy_list?regionId=1&amp;pg=4">4</a></dd>
<dd><a href="http://rabota.ua/jobsearch/vacancy_list?regionId=1&amp;pg=5">5</a></dd>
<dd><a href="http://rabota.ua/jobsearch/vacancy_list?regionId=1&amp;pg=6">6</a></dd>
<dd style="position: absolute; right: 50px;">
<a id="centerZone_vacancyList_gridList_linkNext" href="http://rabota.ua/jobsearch/vacancy_list?regionId=1&amp;pg=2">next »</a>
...
```

I'd like to crawl the links to obtain one big list of existing vacancies as JSON or XML.

Comment: u might want to take a look at this lib for parsing http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: The question is specifically about scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a [sitemap](http://rabota.ua/sitemap.xml) you can use, it is probably easier to use.

You can use the [SitemapSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I've found **solution**. Hope, it'll be helpful for others...

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy_sample.items import ScrapySampleItem

class ScrapyOrgSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "scrapy"
    allowed_domains = ["scrapy.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://blog.scrapy.org/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        next_page =
            hxs.select("//div[@class='pagination']/a[@class='next_page']/@href").extract()
        if not not next_page:
            yield Request(next_page[0], self.parse)

        posts = hxs.select("//div[@class='post']")
        items = []
        for post in posts:
            item = ScrapySampleItem()
            item["title"] = post.select("div[@class='bodytext']/h2/a/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = post.select("div[@class='bodytext']/h2/a/@href").extract()
            item["content"] = post.select("div[@class='bodytext']/p/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

!!